# How to avoid message [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [42S02] to pop up when you press "Refresh All" button?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to catch errors and send my own alert message when a query don't run because the inquired table do not exist. When I press "Refresh All" on the ribbon button all the queries on the work book runs, it could be possible that one of the tables inquired do not exist, in such case I want to capture that error and create my own personalized MsgBox message instead Microsoft Excel display a dialog box. I create a AfterRefresh procedure on a class module that works correctly but I can't find the way to handle the error to avoid that annoying dialog box. I already tried:  Application.DisplayAlerts = False when I open the workbook, or On Error GoTo [Label]  ... Resume [Label], etc, but so far nothing works.

Any Idea how I can handle this?

Does the Error Handling even goes in the "AfterRefresh" procedure?

I ask this because if I refresh all the queries assigning a macro on my own button, meaning, not from "Refresh All" from the ribbon but from a button I created, the dialog message do not pop up.

Regards

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
  
        If Success Then
            MsgBox "Query " & MyQuery.ListObject.Name & " refreshed"
        else
            MsgBox "Query " & MyQuery.ListObject.Name & " failed"
        End If

End Sub
```

[image]